# Failed to load script on another pc

Tags: pyinstaller

I just finished working on a GUI based application and I created an executable for it. I'm trying to test the application on another pc and I get 'Fatal Error Detected (i.e Failed to load script) on a message box.

I tried to run it using command prompt to see what the actual error is and only the error pops up (Nothing is logged into the command prompt window).

Please, I would like to know how to get the actual error on the other PCs so I can find a solution.
P.S: The application works on my own computer.

Comment: In my limited experience, unless you are running the same version of the same OS on both computers, you PyInstaller-compiled application is unlikely to work correctly or at all.

Comment: @dandan78 Okay, thanks for the reply. Is there any way I can work around this?

Comment: @dandan78 I finally found the error. The icon for the application was in my downloads folder and the path was something like 'C:\Users\xxx\downloads\icon'. I simply put the icon in the folder where all the other icons were and changed the file path in my code and BOOM!!! Everything works fine on other PCs.